# Keeping only highest point in cluster of points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-cluster

i have a cluster of points in particular areas around NZ.

I am only wanting the point with the highest value in this cluster to remain. Also many of the points have the same value, i am just wanting 1 point in the cluster to remain. It does not matter which highest point it is, as long as it is one with the highest value.

Any idea on how to do this?

[image]

[image]

Bottom pic is using focal stats > raster calc and then raster to point
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution in your related post. Use focal statistics (maximum) for neigbourhood of your choice, e.g. 500*500 cells, output - raster, called FC.
Use raster calculator to locate highest points:

```
Con ("DEM">="FC","DEM")
```

Convert output raster to points, e.g.:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, i just tried this. Works, and agreed better solution then mine. However my end result is still multiple points but with the same value, i still need just 1 point in each area? @FelixIP i posted picture up top

Comment: Just increase search raster in focal statistics. Your dem is faulty, because groups of points indicate completely flat large area.

Comment: I meant massive flat top mountains, good luck to find them in nz

Comment: My raster isn't a DEM - its not showing heights.

Comment: Ok. Change to Con ("DEM">="FC",1), region group and do zonal geometry as table.